# Comma in "Into the wells of vertical rows 2–4, add 100 µl samples of the calibration solutions."

Tags: adverbs, commas

> Into the wells of vertical rows 2–4, add 100 µl samples of the calibration solutions.

Is a comma necessary before "add", or can it be omitted?

"Into the wells of vertical rows 2-4" is an adverbial phrase. I can't find a grammatical rule for such a clause staring a sentence, but it reads better with a comma after it.

Comment: No, a comma is not necessary there. It doesn't read better with a comma, IMO.

Comment: IMO it *does* read better with a comma...but commas are often a matter of individual style and preference.

Comment: Really? Why be so complex? I'd change places: **Add 100 µl samples of the calibration solutions into the wells of *the* vertical rows 2–4.** I think 'the" is needed here.

Comment: The definite article is not needed. In fact, it's ungrammatical. It would be like saying "The lecture is held in the lecture room 222".

Comment: Why be "so complex"? Instructions are often written so that important information is placed at the head of the sentence: "With the circuit breaker off, carefully detach the red and black wires."

Comment: @SovereignSun - one can always spot a fellow Russian by noticing this **the** before "room 222" and similar phrases ^_^

Comment: @TRomano That's why I've always hated instructions!

Comment: Adding a comma to set off a phrase is, for want of a better word, "germanic style".  It's still used in German, and by many Germans when writing English.  It was commonplace in 18th-c. English everywhere.  But it's falling out of favor among Anglophones today, even though still completely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need some points to buy virtual gifts for the holidays, so:

A comma is not needed there.

Strictly speaking, there are  no "grammatical" rules covering the use of commas; commas are from the realm of typography, where there are only conventions. But let's not be sticklers. Let's assume that comma placement reflects a syntactic boundary of some kind, and that there is concord between typography and the prosodic features of language.

When the fronted prepositional phrase is headed by **Into**, the prepositional phrase is closely allied with the verb, inasmuch as **into** expresses movement, not a locus.

> Into the mixture stir two cups of raisins.

To stir into...

"Into the mixture stir" could be spoken as a phrasal unit with hardly any pause between prepositional phrase and verb. That alliance between the preposition and verb all but eliminates the syntactic pause.

In contrast with **into**,  prepositional phrases beginning with **in**,  when it expresses *locus*, are followed by a relatively longer syntactic pause, reflected by a comma:

> In the room, there is a grandfather clock.

**In** is not tied to **is** in the same way that **into** is tied to **stir**.

P.S. If we go out of our way to separate the fronted prepositional phrase headed by **Into** from the verb, and the PP now abuts a noun-phrase, a longer syntactic pause is used, making the comma a more likely choice:

> Into the mixture, two cups of raisins are stirred.

Answer (score 1):

> **Add** 100 µl samples of the calibration solutions **into** the  wells of vertical rows 2-4.

The  action, *adding the samples*, is the first step. Verbs usually precede place: e.g.

> ***Pour*** (V) a glass of red wine (DIRECT O) **into** (PREP) the saucepan (INDIRECT O).

That sequence will always sound better than the grammatically correct instruction:

> ***Into*** the saucepan **pour** a glass of red wine.
>   ***Into*** the wells of vertical rows 2–4 **add** 100 µl samples of the calibration solutions.

But note, in neither example did I feel the necessity to interrupt the flow by introducing a comma. But the placement of commas, are often left to the whims of their authors, so if the OP *feels* that a comma is necessary, then by all means, he should add one. The meaning of the instruction, or its sequence of events will be unaffected either way.